# 'licensekey' is an invalid connection string attribute - OracleConnection

Tags: oracle, .net-core, connection-string, dapper, devart

I'm using Dapper and getting this error while trying to connect to Oracle Database

```
                return new OracleConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("CONNECTIONNAME"));
```

My ConnectionString looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CONNECTIONNAME": "User Id=***;
     Password=***;
     Data Source=MYDB;
     connection timeout=6000;
     licensekey=***"
  },
```

Does anyone have some idea how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: As DBA I have never seen that you can give a license key as argument for an Oracle database connection and there is a good reason for this: Oracle Database licenses are not stored in database or file systems (very different from license keys in Windows). I suggest to try to remove this parameter.

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/LicensingStandard.html) and more troubleshooting about licensekey is [invalid](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Licensing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm) for list of valid Connection String Attributes. **licensekey** is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists, contact us via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html and specify:

1. The full stack trace of the exception.
2. Are you working with .NET Framework (C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\dotConnect\Oracle) and .NET Standard (https://www.nuget.org/packages/devart.data.oracle) Devart.* assemblies?